Bluetooth Pairing PIN Authentication
I have a NUC which I run Kubuntu 22.04 on. The NUC has a built in wifi/bluetooth card which I can connect to with no issues. However, the NUC bluetooth connectivity is prone to issue so I bought a USB bluetooth dongle to get a better connection. The issue is when I try to connect my bluetooth keyboard (Keychron K2 Pro) to the USB dongle it requests a PIN to be entered on the device which of course I cannot enter. The prompt only occurs if I try to connect to the dongle. I have never been prompted to enter a PIN when I connect to the NUC's built in bluetooth.
Does anyone have any idea why this only occurs with the bluetooth dongle? Is there a way to disable this authentication?
Thanks.
